# How can I use A dialog with No BUTTON and automatically Closes? On BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, rim-4.5, blackberry-os-v4.5

I need to use a dialog. That appears 2-3 seconds and after closes automatically.
Which object should I use On BlackBerry?

Comment: I find information dialog, But I couldn't fınd how to use..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that extends PopupScreen and use a [TimerTask](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/java/util/TimerTask.html) to automatically close it.  So you would have code in your constructor that looks sort of like this:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

        public void run()
        {
            if(TestScreen.this.isDisplayed())
            {
                synchronized (Application.getEventLock())
                {
                    TestScreen.this.close();
                }
            }
        }

    }, WAIT_TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use

```
Status.show(String message)
```

> Shows a status screen for two seconds.

or

```
Status.show(String message, Bitmap bitmap, int time)
```

> Shows a status screen with specified
>   icon, for specified time.